Zip file is only partially downloaded
I am trying to download a zip file with Python 3 requests:
try:
    r = requests.get(BASEURL, stream=True)
    with open(localfiletitle, 'wb') as fd:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, fd)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    send_notice_mail("Error downloading the file:", e)
    return False   

but I am always getting a partial, invalid file. I have also tried using urllib.request, and in that case I am getting http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead error.

did you tried instaling actual zip file from a source ? You can check whether the problem is about your system or your code

What happens if you don't use stream=True?

I tried removing stream=True, same result. I can successfully download the file manually, from web browser.

You need to extract the value from content, not raw
with open(localfiletitle, 'wb') as fd:
    shutil.copyfileobj(io.BytesIO(r.content), fd)

You can also work with it without saving it using ZipFile
data = io.BytesIO(r.content)
with ZipFile(data) as zip_file:
    ...

